# Import PDF as `Graphics`

Tags: import, pdf-format

How can I import a PDF file as a `Graphics` object. When calling `Import["filename.pdf","PDF"]`, Mathematica always imports the PDF as a list of `Image`s.

If there is a way to import it as `Graphics` can this be set as the default?

Comment: Import["filename.pdf",{"PDF", "PageGraphics"}]

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thank you this works! Is there also a way to make this the default behavior?

Comment: New behavior (and solution) documented [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html).

Comment: @Qbyte I don't think there is a "legitimate" way to set the old behavior as the default behavior: changing the default behavior of built-in functions is discouraged. You can use the short form `Import["filename.pdf", "PageGraphics"]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can read on the Documentation page "[Incompatible Changes since Mathematica Version 1](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html#1811902644)" (thanks [Alan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/252716/import-pdf-as-graphics?noredirect=1#comment631676_252716) for the link!), starting from version 12.2

> The default element for `Import[file,"PDF"]` has been changed from `Graphics` to `Image`. Previous behavior can be accessed by specifying `"PageGraphics"` upon import.

There are two ways to do this:

1. Full form:

   ```
   Import["filename.pdf", {"PDF", "PageGraphics"}]

   ImportString[string, {"PDF", "PageGraphics"}]
   ```
2. Short form:

   ```
    Import["filename.pdf", "PageGraphics"]

    ImportString[string, "PageGraphics"]
   ```

> Is there also a way to make this the default behavior?

I don't think there is a "legitimate" way to set the old behavior as the default behavior: changing the default behavior of built-in functions is discouraged. Just use `"PageGraphics"` instead of `"PDF"` as the second argument of `Import` when importing pdf files (starting from *Mathematica* version 12.2).

Alternatively, you can use the [legacy](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v12.1/ref/format/PDF.html) (pre-version 12.2) syntax and specify `"Pages"` as the second argument - in version 12.3.1 this syntax is undocumented but still works (thanks [chyanog](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2090/chyanog) for [pointing this out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/252716/import-pdf-as-graphics/252741?noredirect=1#comment631707_252741)!):

```
Import["filename.pdf", "Pages"]

ImportString[string, "Pages"]
```

The advantage is that you can use the same code for the new and legacy versions and avoid the usage of constructs like

```
ImportString[string, If[$VersionNumber >= 12.2, {"PDF", "PageGraphics"}, 
                                                {"PDF", "Pages"}]]
```

The disadvantage is that the support for this (now undocumented) syntax can be dropped in future versions of *Mathematica*.

Comment: A little shorter, `Import["filename.pdf", "Pages"]`.

Comment: @chyanog In version 12.3.1 this [legacy](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v12.1/ref/format/PDF.html) syntax is undocumented but still works, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

An internal hack, and therefore not guaranteed to work in future, to change the default element to `"PageGraphics"` is as follows:

```
System`ConvertersDump`defaultElement[Import]["PDF"] = 
 {"PageGraphics"};
Import["ExampleData/mathematica.pdf"]
Head /@ %
(*  {Graphics}  *)
```

The change will persist until reset or the kernel session ends. It should be relatively safe.  The default definition is

```
System`ConvertersDump`defaultElement[Import]["PDF"] = 
 {"PageImages"};
```

Comment: Thank you! How did you find this setting?

Comment: @Qbyte, Darn, but I've forgotten. Here's a different way. I think to myself: "How does `"PageImages"` show up in the code? So `foo = Trace[Import["ExampleData/mathematica.pdf"], TraceInternal -> True];
Position[foo, "PageImages"]` shows where. The first few positions end in `32`; these are each a list of all the PDF elements available. So take the first one that does not end in `32` (it ends in `1`) and examine this part of `foo`. Repeatedly take away the last number of the position until you get to `foo[[4, 2, 3, 9, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 30, 1, 18, 15, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4]]`, which hits paydirt.

Comment: I did look up `RegisterFormat` (search this site), and examined `Import.m` in `Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Formats/PDF` starting in the installation directory (MacOS). There a `"DefaultElement"` is registered, so I searched for ``?*onvert*`*efault*`` (you can never be sure that internal functions will start with a capital).